# How do you get Scripts enabled? I can't get Scripts to become enabled on the windows command line or PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-line

Hey guys I can't seem to get Scripts to run in the VS code editor. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: On Windows workstations, PowerShell script execution is _disabled_ by default. Enable it with [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy).`-Scope` accepts one of 3 scopes; more specific ones have higher precedence: `LocalMachine` (requires admin rights), `CurrentUser`, or `Process` (current process only). The PowerShell CLI accepts a process-specific `-ExecutionPolicy <policy>` too . Execution policies can also be set via GPO, in which case they cannot be changed or overridden via `Set-ExecutionPolicy` or the CLI.

Comment: If your problem is _not_ related to PowerShell's execution policies, please ask a new question that explains the problem in detail, ideally in the form of a [mcve].  [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) contains general tips.